# MinMaxScaler with range from multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, minmax

I have an OHLC dataframe (Open, High, Low, Close) for sensor data on a per minute basis. I need to scale the values but all with the same scale. The scale needs to use the minimum and maximum of any of the four columns. For example, the minimum could be in column 'Low' and the maximum could be in the column 'High'. Based on that range (`min(df['low'])` - `max(df['high'])`), I want to fit the scaler.

I am currently using the `MinMaxScaler` from sklearn.preprocessing. However, I can only fit it to one column. So if I fit it to column `df['open']` and transform another column, the values are no longer between 0 and 1 but can be < 0 and > 1.

How can I use the full range of all columns in the scaler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anybody ends up on this page, I actually found another way of doing this, which involves reshaping the data using Numpy and feeding that into the scaler. Reshaping back and creating a new dataframe from that sorted my issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

#kudo's to Nick, I used his df to illustrate my example.
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Open': [1, 1.1, 0.9, 0.9],
  'High': [1.2, 1.2, 1.1, 1.3],
  'Low': [1, 1.0, 0.8, 0.7],
  'Close': [1.1, 1.2, 0.8, 1.2] 
})

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df_np = scaler.fit_transform(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1))
df = pd.DataFrame(df_np.reshape(4,-1), columns=df.columns)

#   Open    High    Low Close
# 0 0.500000    0.833333    0.500000    0.666667
# 1 0.666667    0.833333    0.500000    0.833333
# 2 0.333333    0.666667    0.166667    0.166667
# 3 0.333333    1.000000    0.000000    0.833333
```

Comment: If this worked better for you than my answer, you should accept it (when you can). Out of curiosity, have you done any performance comparison?

Answer (score 1):

You could normalise all columns by doing the math yourself, using `df.min().min()` and `df.max().max()` to get the minimum and maximum values over the entire dataframe, or more simply `df['Low'].min()` and `df['High'].max()` to get the minimum/maximum values from the `Low` and `High` column respectively. For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Open': [1, 1.1, 0.9, 0.9],
  'High': [1.2, 1.2, 1.1, 1.3],
  'Low': [1, 1.0, 0.8, 0.7],
  'Close': [1.1, 1.2, 0.8, 1.2] 
})
df
#    Open  High  Low  Close
# 0   1.0   1.2  1.0    1.1
# 1   1.1   1.2  1.0    1.2
# 2   0.9   1.1  0.8    0.8
# 3   0.9   1.3  0.7    1.2

min = df.min().min()    # df['Low'].min()
max = df.max().max()    # df['High'].max()
norm = (df - min) / (max - min)
norm
#        Open      High       Low     Close
# 0  0.500000  0.833333  0.500000  0.666667
# 1  0.666667  0.833333  0.500000  0.833333
# 2  0.333333  0.666667  0.166667  0.166667
# 3  0.333333  1.000000  0.000000  0.833333
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work for me I think. Great example and explanation!